# Rewrite path to $_GET

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite this: `domain.com/foobar` to `domain.com?p=foobar`.

I don't need subdirectories or multiple variables for this.

I am using nginx, and most other answers where either not what I wanted, or apache.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it using the following rule in the `location / {}` block:

`rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?p=$1 last;`